# make the arXiv timestamp a clickable hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, arxiv

When you upload a preprint to the arxiv.org repository, it generates a timestamp for it (I think this happens once the moderators approve it), and this is usually printed on the first page, vertically and in grey font.

Is there a simple way to make this a clickable hyperlink?

I don't have a MWE, but one could look e.g. at the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.04265
I suspect it is performed by the JHEP3.cls, but I'm unable to find the place in the code where this is achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is only available for plain latex and tex submissions in arXiv. The code that stamps pdflatex presently is based on using `pdfpages`, which would then [break all hyperlinks in the resultant pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page=2), which is a known issue with both arXiv's codebase and the `pdfpages` documentation (link above will take you there).

It's on arXiv's docket to look into other mechanisms for such document stamping in the future, but the timeline is unclear.

TL/DR: If you want a clickable arXiv-id stamp, you have to use latex or plain tex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could you explain what "plain latex and tex submissions" means? I've submitted latex sources to arxiv for which I don't have the clickable hyperlink, so I don't see what other people do to have this feature.

Comment: This was perhaps an unclear way of saying that you cannot use pdflatex for compilation if you want to have a clickable arXiv-id link, at this time. See for example the link generated at [arXiv:2210.06638](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.06638) whereby the arXiv-id stamp is clickable in the pdf.

Comment: I see, I've been using \pdfoutput=1 which forces arxiv to use pdflatex.

Comment: Setting that flag to `1` forces the compiler out of `dvi` mode. Usually AutoTeX can figure out which to use, but in general most people are going to view the pdf anyway, rarely do they download the source or need to upload postscript figures (unless your target journal requires it). In the future, we'll likely have an option to set the compiler at submission time, I imagine.